# zoomToPoint - wrong coordinates after panning / zooming

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, fabricjs

## Steps to reproduce

1. Use the mousewheel to zoom in and out and then press the "go to blue dot" button

### Expected Behavior

pressing the button should always bring the blue dot to the center of the screen and the zoom level to : 2 , no matter what previous image state was before (zoomed or panned to other location)

### Actual Behavior

the image moves to random locations ? it seems that panning the image / zooming it,
 mess up the entire move to function.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jrdjJm

```
$("#go_blue").click(function(){
canvas.zoomToPoint(point,2);
});
```

```js
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src ="http://content.worldcarfans.co/2008/6/medium/9080606.002.1M.jpg";
var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas("imageCanvas");

var dot = new fabric.Circle({
    top: 250,
    left: 250,
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center',
    radius: 20,
    fill: 'blue'
});

var point = new fabric.Point(250,250);

var group;

$(img).on('load',function(){
    image = new fabric.Image(img, {
        centeredRotation: true,
        centeredScaling: true,
        top: 0,
        left: 0
    });
    group = new fabric.Group([ image, dot ], {
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center'
        //angle: -10
    });

    canvas.add(group);

});

canvas.on("mouse:move", function(event) {
    currentMouseY = Math.round(event.e.y - canvas._offset.top);
    currentMouseX = Math.round(event.e.x - canvas._offset.left);
});

function zoom(delta, target) {
    var factor = 0.8;
    if (delta < 0) {
        factor = 1/factor;
    }

    // Zoom into the group.
    group.setScaleX(group.getScaleX() * factor);
    group.setScaleY(group.getScaleY() * factor);
    // Calculate displacement of zooming position.
    var dx = (currentMouseX - group.getLeft()) * (factor - 1),
        dy = (currentMouseY - group.getTop()) * (factor - 1);
    // Compensate for displacement.
    group.setLeft(group.getLeft() - dx);
    group.setTop(group.getTop() - dy);

    canvas.renderAll();
}

$(canvas.wrapperEl).on("mousewheel", function (event) {
    var target = canvas.findTarget(event);
    if (target) {
        var delta = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120;
        zoom(delta, target);
    }
    event.preventDefault() && false;
});


$("#go_blue").click(function(){
    canvas.zoomToPoint(point,2);
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div style="position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 11px;
    z-index: 10000;">
    Use the mousewheel to zoom in and out and then press the "go to blue dot" btn - it should pan to the blue dot no matter what the zoom level is.
</div>

<button id="go_blue" style="position: fixed;
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    z-index: 10000;">move to blue dot</button>

<div style="margin-top: 80px;">
    <canvas id="imageCanvas" width='800' height='600'>Your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas</canvas>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.6/fabric.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What seems to be happening is that the "go blue" button zooms in on the canvas itself, not on the image.  This causes two problems:

- The image and the canvas operate on different position systems.  Moving to the point (250, 250) on the canvas does not definitively correspond to any point on the image since the image can be moved.
- The image and the canvas do not share zoom levels.  The zoom function handles zooming in on the image and not the canvas.  When the zoom function is called it will zoom in further on the image, regardless of the image's own zoom due to the factor of 2 attached to it.

This is the reason for the weird behavior, as well as why the go blue button seems to stop working after the first click.  In my example I corrected this by altering the "go blue" listener to instead work on the image:

```
$("#go_blue").click(function() {
    zoom(2 / group.getScaleX(), group); (I modified the zoom function a little)
    group.setLeft(point.left);
    group.setTop(point.top);
    group.setCoords();
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```

This just returns the image to its starting location at regular zoom, which makes it off by a constant amount from the blue dot.  I tampered with things and got the blue dot pretty close to center.  If you modify the constant being divided in the zoom call within the listener, you can get the "go blue" to center on different zoom levels.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qavqwX